# read data from a huge CSV file efficiently

Tags: python, csv

I was trying to process my huge CSV file (more than 20G), but the process was killed when reading the whole CSV file into memory. To avoid this issue, I am trying to read the second column line by line.

For example, the 2nd column contains data like

1. xxx, computer is good
2. xxx, build algorithm

   ```
   import collections

   wordcount = collections.Counter()

   with open('desc.csv', 'rb') as infile:
       for line in infile:
            wordcount.update(line.split())
   ```

My code is working for the whole columns, how to only read the second column without using CSV reader?

Comment: You could use iteration (for loops/yield) instead of loading a lot of data into memory. I don't know how much control you have over the individual parts, so I can't give an example.

Comment: @DennisKuypers, Thanks. what do you mean by how much control?

Comment: What I mean is: Can you change the code or are you just taking the result of one library into the next. Maybe you can use `for something in descs:` to iterate over results one by one. You probably have to omit the `.tolist()`. Again, I don't know the libraries, so I can not tell you the proper way

Comment: @DennisKuypers I modified the question, is that clear to you?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, calling `csv.reader(infile)` opens and reads the whole file...which is where your problem lies.

You can just read line-by-line and parse manually:

```
X=[]

with open('desc.csv', 'r') as infile:    
   for line in infile:
      # Split on comma first
      cols = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]

      # Grab 2nd "column"
      col2 = cols[1]

      # Split on spaces
      words = [x.strip() for x in col2.split(' ')]
      for word in words:     
         if word not in X:
            X.append(word)

for w in X:
   print w
```

That will keep a smaller chunk of the file in memory at a given time (one line).  However, you may still potentially have problems with variable `X` increasing to quite a large size, such that the program will error out due to memory limits.  Depends how many unique words are in your "vocabulary" list

Comment: Thanks, but your example only works for the first column, right? If it was the 3rd column, x.strip() would not be right, correct?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood what you meant by columns.  I assumed "computer is good" was on its own line, followed by "build algorithm" on the next line.  Where I used `x.strip()`/`split()` could be `csv.reader()` just as easily if that works for your input files.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. So it is not good to use CSV reader when file is too huge, right?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code in your question is reading the 20G file and splitting each line into space separated tokens then creating a counter that keeps a count of **every** unique token. I'd say that is where your memory is going.

From the manual [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) is an iterator

> a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile.
>   csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and
>   returns a string each time its next() method is called

so it is fine to iterate through a huge file using `csv.reader`.

```
import collections

wordcount = collections.Counter()

with open('desc.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        # count words in strings from second column
        wordcount.update(row[1].split())
```